# Error al ingresar diagonal invertida en Vim

Tags: windows10, vim

Hoy instale Vim en mi pc con Windows 10 y cuando intente escribir la diagonal invertida con la combinacion ALT+92...
en Vim solo me aparecio un 1 y un 2 pequeños en la pantalla y me gustaria que alguien me ayudara a solucionarlo ya que no tengo idea de como escribir la diagonal invertida en Vim.

Comment: proba con ctrl+v ( insert )  092 o ctrl+Q 092

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas usar los [digraphs](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html) que es una manera de ingresar caracteres que no encuentras en un teclado. En primer lugar puedes consultarlos:

```
:digraphs!
```

Esto mostrara todos los caracteres especiales que ya están definidos, obviamente puedes definir nuevos. Todos estos se pueden dibujar ingresando dos caracteres {char1} y {char2}, En el caso de la barra invertida, vemos  que está documentada así:

```
// \ 92
```

Es decir para dibujar la barra invertida usaremos dos barras comunes. Hay dos formas:

```
<CTRL-K> {char1}{char2}
```

o bien

```
{char1}<BACKSPACE>{char2}
```

Pero esto último solo si está habilitada la opción [`digraphs`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27digraph%27), lo más probable que en tu caso te arregles con `<CTRL-K>//`

Comment: gracias me ha funcionado el modo CTRL+K //, yo uso vim desde la linea de comando, y cuando intentaba usar las tantas formas que sale en internet, no funcionaba o se quitaba el modo insertar

Answer (score 0):

Para los que tienen el mismo problema que yo, les comento que me funciono presionar la tecla "AltGr" + la tecla que se encuentra al lado derecho del cero para ingresar la diagonal invertida en el editor Vim.